# Display php data json_encoded with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I convert my php code to json with json_encoded function.
After I write ajax code to display my data in ajax but when running don't display my data.

My json code:

```
[
{"Name":"fasher","Description":"2500 kg","Namyandegi":"20,500,000","Bazar":"22,410,000"}
,
{"Name":"shob","Description":"1000 kg","Namyandegi":"10,400,000","Bazar":"12,220,000"}
]
```

and ajax file:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
            $(document).ready(function(){

                    $.getJSON('saipa.php', function(data) {

                            $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                                    $('ul').append('<li id="shoker">' + val.Name + ' ' + val.Description + ' ' + val.Namyandegi + ' ' + val.Bazar + '</li>');
                            });
                    });

            });
            </script>

<body>
     <ul><li id="shoker"></li></ul>
</body>
```

Comment: what happens instead? any errors in the browser console? on the server?

Comment: do console.log(data); and tell what result you are getting

Comment: `console.log(data)`, see what you really got. if your script is issuing ANY php warnings/errors, those will become part of the json string and corrupt it.

Comment: I use wam server localhost... with firebug consol and network I dont see any error.. all requests are 200 OK

Comment: is your php function echo any output?

Comment: no ..........................

Answer (score 0):

Use the index overload `$.each()`

```
$.each(data, function(index) {
    $('ul').append('<li id="shoker">' + data[index].Name + ' ' + 
                                        data[index].Description + ' ' + 
                                        data[index].Namyandegi + ' ' + 
                                        data[index].Bazar + '</li>'
             );
});
```